# WordPress Database Re-installed (Hacked)

Tags: security, hacked

Over the past 2 days, exactly in the hour of 8 o'clock, my WordPress blog has rendered with one sample post, as if the databases are being reinstalled. The database usually holds around 2-3 years of posts which all get deleted.

Weirdly though, all the file system stays intact, and it takes a database backup restore to fix it.

Does anyone have any advice on what to look for to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: There are so many possibilities here. Can you reproduce this on another system (VM, docker, etc.)? If so, it is probably your application. If not, it might be something out of your control (contact your web host).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of your plugins/themes is vulnerable and allows anyone to modify your database. For example ThemeGrill themes have such vulnerability lately.

Another possibility is that your site got hacked and there's some backdoor placed on it.

In both cases you should:

- check all your site
- clean it
- update it
- secure it.